# Is there a way to speed up C++ compilation times in Solaris Sun Studio 12?

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, performance, solaris, sunstudio

Since I am compiling my C++ code on a very server box (32 or 64 cores in total), is there a way of tweaking compiler options to speed up the compilation times? E.g. to tell compiler to compile independent .cpp files using multiple threads.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sun Studio includes parallel build support in the included `dmake` version of make.
See [the dmake manual](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19205-01/819-5273/aexaz/index.html) for details.

Comment: dmake -j 64 has reduced a compilation time from over two minutes to under 4 seconds... fantastic.

Answer (score 4):

This depends on what toolchain you're using.

If you're using GNU Make, then add `-j 32` to your make invocation to tell Make to start 32 jobs (for example) in parallel.  Just make sure that you're not exhausting RAM and thrashing your swap file as a result.

Answer (score 3):

Use something like Boost JAM which does this sort of multithreading for you - and from my experience much more efficiently than multi-threaded make.

Answer (score 0):

Sun's C++ compiler also has an `-xjobs` option that makes the compiler fork multiple threads internally.  For this to be efficient you would probably have to pass all .cc files to a single invocation of CC.